# How do you have Ctrl + Alt + T duplicate a terminal tab in Freya?

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I was able to do this just fine in the previous version of elementary OS. But I've been unable to find a method to do it in Freya.

I want <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+Tto duplicate a tab in Freya with the same directory. So if the current tab is in `~/Workspace/Websites` I can just press the key sequence and it'll open a second tab in `~/Workspace/Websites` as well instead of having to right click on the tab and clicking **duplicate**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just set `org.pantheon.terminal.settings.follow-last-tab` in dconf to true.
Or you can execute in terminal:
`gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings follow-last-tab true`

Comment: Perfect solution. Cheers! The devs should add an option for this in the GUI though